# Cannot set a default item in combobox in certain project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, default-value

In my VB.NET solution in Visual Studio 2015 I have some projects which contains some Windows Forms items. In general I know how to programmatically set a default item in a combobox control by using `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0` instruction. However this instruction do not work in one of my projects and my combobox is always blank when program runs. I also cannot add programmatically new items to combobox in this project, I can do it only using Properties sidebar.

My program runs normally, Visual Studio do not see any errors, instructions which concerns my combobox are executed but don't affect it. In other projects everything works well.

Have you ever encountered something like this? Maybe I've unconsciously changed some options in this project and that's why the problem occur?

**EDIT:**

Problem solved. I didn't noticed that during copying some code I accidently also copied `InitializeComponent()` instruction. Without this duplicated initialize instruction everything is working well and I have ability to manage default value of my combobox correctly.

Comment: You should edit and post the code used to populate this combobox. It might even be helpful to get a snapshot of the combobox dropped down and show the first few items in the dropdown list. Is it possible that you have a blank entry as the 1st item (0 index) in the list and that is why it doesn't appear to be changing? Sound like this combobox has a datasource that gives it its collection.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMay for your advices. After reading your comment I checked my code again and I've found the source of my problem. Thanks for your contribution.